# Submit JSON data as request body in an Apache CXF REST Service

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, cxf

I know this has been asked before, but going through multiple answers did not help me solve my issue. So here it is: I'm a newbie trying to create a REST service using Apache CXF. I'm trying to write a POST method and send the data as JSON in the request body(using POSTMAN in Google Chrome to do this).

My interface looks something like this:

```
     @Path("/")
     @Produces("application/json")
     public interface MyService{

         @POST
         @Path("/addNote/{id}")
         @Consumes("application/json")
         NoteResponse addNote(@PathParam("id") Long id, @QueryParam("note")Note note);

         // OTHER @GET METHODS THAT WORK WELL
     }
```

My implmentation:

```
    @WebService(name = "testservice")
    public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{

        @Override
        public NoteResponse addNote(Long id, Note note){
            // SOME IMPLEMENTATION
        }
        // OTHER @GET METHOD IMPLEMENTATIONS THAT WORK
    }
```

I've read in some answers that I do not need the @QueryParam on my note annotation, instead just put and @XMLRootElement on my Note class, but doing that and trying going on localhost:8080/rest/addNote/1 will NOT call my addNote method.

The problem I am facing now is that the note parameter comes null.

Here's the JSON I've sent via POSTMAN:

```
    {
        "note":{
            "id": 4958,
            "anotherId": 7886,
            "comment": "salut",
            "mail": "mail@mail.com",
            "gregorianDate": "01-01-2016",
            "type": "INFO"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try changing your interface definition of API addNote to this:

```
NoteResponse addNote(@PathParam("id") Long id, Note note);
```

And send this JSON string via POSTMAN:

```
        {
            "id": 4958,
            "anotherId": 7886,
            "comment": "salut",
            "mail": "mail@mail.com",
            "gregorianDate": "01-01-2016",
            "type": "INFO"
        }
```

This should work.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it did not work. The addNote method is not called at all.

Comment: try this URL - localhost:8080/rest/MyService/addNote/1

Comment: I've tried but there is "No service found". The CXF Servlet is mapped to /rest and the jaxrs:server address points to /testservice. The URL I've been going to is localhost:8080/rest/testservice/addNote/1 but the addNote method is not called. It is only called when I provide the @QueryParam for note. And note is always null.

Comment: just noticed that you have the @WebService annotation on your class. This is a jax-ws annotation which is leading the class to be not restful at all. You don't need this for Rest. Add the javax.ws.rs.Path annotation instead of WebServices.

Comment: I don't know what was going wrong in that project, but after 2 days I wrote a new project, from scratch and followed your answer. It went smoothly. Thank you! I'm gonna mark your answer as accepted as it was very helpful.

Comment: glad to be of some help!